# shell access to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created a durpal site in minutes using cloud formation service and I can see the ec2 instance. 
But I am not able to log-in to the instance because I do not know which key pair was used.

I need to take the backup of mysql database using "mysqldump" utility and I need the shell access to the instance. How do I connect to the ec2 instance where drupal is installed through cloud formation?

Answer (score 0):

By default, aws however, does not give you shell access to the ec2 instance. You need to create the drupal site based on a template in order to gain the root access.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/

Use the template that says: "Single EC2 Instance with local MySQL database" You will be able to specify the key pair that will allow you to connect using putty.